# Hide a datatable row on click on R/Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I would like to make a row of an R datatable disappear when the user clicks on it on Shiny.

Minimum, reproducible example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("DTOut"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$DTOut <- DT::renderDataTable({datatable(iris)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you!

EDIT :
Following up on Stéphane's answer, his solution works but I can't integrate it into a Shiny app

```
ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("DTOut"))

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$DTOut <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(iris),
        callback = JS("table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {", " table.row(this).remove().draw();", "})"))}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I've used this solution in the past: https://github.com/stefaneng/Shiny-DeleteRowsDT/blob/master/app.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {",
  "  table.row(this).remove().draw();",
  "});"
)

datatable(iris, callback = JS(js))
```

---

## Edit

The above works in Shiny if you set `server=FALSE` in `renderDT`. If you want to use `server=TRUE` (the default), you can proceed as follows:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)


callback <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('clickedRow', $(this).index(), {priority: 'event'});",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- iris
  
  output$dtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat,
      selection = "none",
      callback = JS(callback)
    )
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable")
  
  observeEvent(input$clickedRow, {
    dat <<- dat[-(input$clickedRow + 1), ]
    # below, set rownames=FALSE if you set rownames=FALSE in datatable()
    replaceData(proxy, dat, rownames = TRUE, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you Stéphane, it works well like that, but I can't get it in a Shiny


ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("DTOut"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$DTOut <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(iris),
                                      callback = JS("table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {",
                                                              "  table.row(this).remove().draw();",
                                                              "})"))

}

Comment: @Juliette Hmm strange. Did you try with `server = FALSE`?

Comment: Ça fonctionne avec server = FALSE, merci Stéphane !